# Phaser 3 - How to detect if all components are sleeping?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I am new to Phaser Framework and I wanted to try making some prototype of 2D pool game from top down perspective. The problem that I have right now is detecting if **all balls** have stopped moving before restarting.

I use `Physics.Matter` and here is the source code when `create` so far:

```
this.matter.world.setBounds(0, 0, 720, 1280, 32, false, false, false, true);
this.add.image(400, 300, 'sky');

var ball = this.matter.add.image(360, 1000, 'ball');
ball.setCircle();
ball.setVelocity(-5, -20);
ball.setBounce(0.5);

for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
  var target = this.matter.add.image(Phaser.Math.Between(400,450), Phaser.Math.Between(400,450), 'target');
  target.setCircle();
  target.setVelocity(0, 0);
  target.setBounce(0.7);
  target.setFriction(0, 0.01);
  target.setSleepEvents(true, true);
}

this.matter.world.on('sleepstart', function() {console.log('sleepstart');});
this.matter.world.on('sleepend', function() {console.log('sleepend');});
```

This would detect if each `target` has slept but I need to detect if ALL of them stopped moving. I cannot count how many has slept because sometimes when a `target` has entered sleep state, there is a chance some other body will bounce off it and woke it up again.

Is there any way to globally detect them?

EDIT: As a fallback plan I add a basic JS function to be called whenever `update` is called and count the sleeping bodies, which looks like it **should not** be a proper way:

```
var isActive = false;

// Some commands here that changes isActive = true

function onupdate() {
  if (isActive) {
    var bodyCount = this.matter.world.getAllBodies().filter(o => o.isSleeping === true).length;
    console.log(bodyCount);
    if (bodyCount >= 11) {
      isActive = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put all objects you want to track into a phaser group (https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.GameObjects.Group.html) and iterate over the items in the group, to see if all have the property `isSleeping` set to `true`;

> **Warning:** I can't say how performant this solution is, youre use case. If it is too slow, I would setup a counter variable, and count it down / up on `sleepstart` and `sleepend`. And when the counter is `0` all are sleeping.

**Here a working demo, how I would do it:**
*(explaination are in the code, as comments)*

```js
// fix to prevent 'Warnings' in stackoverflow console
console.warn = _ => _

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 400,
    height: 100,
    scene: { create },
    physics: {
        default: 'matter',
        matter: {
            debug: true,
            setBounds: {
                x: 0,
                y: 0,
                width: 400,
                height: 100
            },
            enableSleeping: true
        }
    }
};

function create(){

    // create the Phaser Group
    this.targets = this.add.group();
    
    for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        var target = this.matter.add.image(200, 0, 10, 10, 'target');
        target.setCircle();
        target.setBounce(0.7);
        target.setFriction(0, 0.01);
        target.setSleepEvents(true, true);

        // Add Item to the Group
        this.targets.add(target);
    }

    this.matter.world.on('sleepstart', function(event, item){
        // Check all targets are sleeping
        if(!this.targets.getChildren().some( target => !target.body.isSleeping)){
            console.log('all are sleeping');
        }
      }, this); // <- pass the scene as context

    this.matter.world.on('sleepend', function() {console.log('sleepend');});

}

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```

Comment: I think this is it. I haven't tested it performance-wise, but this accidentally also solves my other bug when switching back from sleep to awake again on touch. So, +1.